# Functions defined at x, when f(x)=0/0

Tags: limits

I am a bit rusty on my math. Is this function defined at x=0?

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{N} \frac{1-e^{i2\pi x}}{1-e^{i2\pi x/N}}$

I know the limit at $x \rightarrow 0$ is $1$, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is defined there. I think this function is supposed to be similar to the delta function, when $x=j-k$ where $j,k$ are integers. So when j=k then x=0 and the function is equal to 1, and at differing integer values of j and k we get 0.

I suppose a directly related question is, is the sinc(x) function defined at x=0? Because I see online that they say sinc(0)=1, but sinc(0)=0/0. Does this have to do with differences between what they call distributions and functions?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Whether $f$ is defined in $0$ depends. $f$ has a removable singularity in $0$, and if your convention is that all removable singularities are always removed, then the function is defined in $0$. Otherwise it is only defined in $0$ if that is explicitly done.

Comment: Ah, sorry I meant to have a 1/N factor in front. You are correct, but I have since changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the function can't be defined at $0$, since the top and bottom both evaluate to $0$, and $0/0$ isn't defined.

If, instead, you define $f$ as:

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1N\frac{1-e^{2\pi ix}}{1-e^{2\pi ix/N}}&x\neq 0\\[.5em] \phantom{\frac1N1-}1&x=0\end{cases}
$$

Then the resulting function is defined at $0$ and, because the limit as $x\to 0$ is $1=f(0)$, $f$ is *continuous* at $0$, which is quite a nice property for it to have.

Comment: If you know how to make that cases bracket look better, please edit this answer.